# Resolve nested sin functions in function for cycloid

Tags: trigonometry, recursion, parametrization, cycloid

I'm looking for a function whos graph looks like a cycloid of a circle with the radius 1. Given the parametric equations for this cycloid: $$\begin{align}x& = t - \sin(t)\\y &= 1 - \cos(t)\end{align}$$

From this, one can find an equation for $t$:$$t = x + \sin(t)$$

This equation for $t$ can be substituted for $t$ in the equation for $y$:$$y = 1-\cos(x+\sin(t))$$

Yet $t$ still remains in the equation for $y$. To get an equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ one can substitute $t$ infinitely many times:

$$y=1-\cos(x+\sin(x+\sin(x+\sin(x+\sin(x+\sin(\cdots))))))$$

Is there a way to resolve these infinetely nested sin functions?

Comment: You can research the differential geometry of cycloids; I don’t know it off by heart but I am completely confident there are simpler and much better formulae out there!

Comment: @FShrike Thanks, I've been trying that ... so far I've been unsucessful. All I've found are parametric equations from which one can derive this infinitely nested function.

Comment: Ah so your question is: given the parametrisation, how does one find $y$ as a function of $x$?

Comment: @FShrike in a sense, yes

Comment: This is an interesting question. Show how you came up with the nested formula, and make the title question/motivation clearer; you’ll then hopefully get some answers

Comment: @FShrike thanks, will do!

Comment: + I edited using “MathJax”: use `$$` signs to render stuff nicely: `$\sin(x+\sin(x))$` renders as $\sin(x+\sin(x))$. I also added some tags relevant to your question. For the moment I’ll say that these problems are usually resolved with a fixed point trick (assuming convergence): $y=f(f(f(\cdots(f(x))\cdots)\implies f(y)=y$ which can help in finding $y$, if convergence can be shown

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the way to find a fixed point for a function like this is using lagrange's inversion theorem which doesn't make the formula much nicer.

Comment: Using the implicit function theorem to obtain a local power series approximation might help, especially since the cycloid is a periodic curve so the locality of the approximation will become unimportant!